# How to reference these tables in an ER Diagram?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, erd

A college assignment requires me to design an ER Diagram for a music platform database. The assignment states that users are able to review songs and albums on the platform. I've designed the following model stating **USERS**, **REVIEWS**, **SONGS** and **ALBUMS** as separate entities. However, I’m not sure how to reference the title that is being reviewed, given that it’s either a song or an album, and that their IDs are in separate tables. Mentioning both would result that one of  them ends up a NULL attribute.
Additionally, each song can either be on an album or not. Not sure how to reference those two either, since it's a conditional statement.

[image: Diagram designed to date]

Any help you can offer is appreciated!

I’ve thought about making both **SONGS** and **ALBUMS** into subtypes of a **RECORDINGS** entity but since they have to be related to each other it feels like a bad practice to specialize them.

Comment: A song by a particular artist can be on more than one album.  A song can be covered by more than one artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "perfect" way to model this scenario and how you model it is a judgement call you need to make based on how these entities are going to be used in your model - try researching supertypes and subtypes for more information.

There are basically 3 ways to model this:

1. As you've modelled it but Reviews has FKs to both Song and Album.
2. Create a Recording entity that contains the common attributes for both Song and Album. Your Review would have an FK to Recording and Recording would have separate FKs to Song and Album
3. Create a Recording entity that includes all attributes for both Songs and Albums. Your Review would have an FK to Recording and Recording would have a self-referential FK to link songs to albums

Ensuring the the correct attributes are populated for any given review would require application logic; I don't believe you can implement it purely in a data model design